# Programs having trouble connecting to internet resources

Tags: networking, tls, iscsi

I am running Windows 8. Recently, a bunch of my programs such as GitHub for Windows, WebStorm, Chrome, etc.. stopped being able to use internet resources. Many say, that there me bay a firewall or proxy problem, so I turned my firewall off, and they still did not work! I trun to the eventlog, and a see a few TLS errors like this:

`A fatal alert was generated and sent to the remote endpoint. This may result in termination of the connection. The TLS protocol defined fatal error code is 70. The Windows SChannel error state is 105.`

And a few iSCSI erros like this:

`Error occurred when processing iSCSI logon request. The request was not retried. Error status is given in the dump data.`

I learned that error code 70 in TLS is: `TLS1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION` which leads me to believe an update will fix. Oddly though, other programs like my browser and git bash work just fine. Has anyone ever encountered a similar problem, and can it be fixed?

Comment: 70 protocol_version "The protocol version the client attempted to negotiate is recognized, but not supported. For example, old protocol versions might be avoided for security reasons. This message is always fatal."

Comment: Would it have anything to do with my issues?

Comment: Quite likely. It depends on what you mean by internet resources. Have you tried restarting everthing? Modem/Router/PC?

Comment: PC yes, modem, router no. My browser can access the internet fine, but online installers, some git clients, and other things can't. From my research, the only other issue I'm finding is a virus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a really old post, but it was solved after a bit by forcing a Windows Update